# Add several new entries to LDAP fails

Tags: ldap, openldap

I can't add more than one record to LDAP. I have blank line before a new DN entry but it seems it doesn't work for some season.

> ldapadd -x -D cn=Manager,dc=hadoop,dc=local -w  -f ldap.ldif
>   ldapadd: attributeDescription "dn": (possible missing newline after
>   line 10, entry "uid=impala,ou=Users,dc=hadoop,dc=local"?) adding new
>   entry "uid=impala,ou=Users,dc=hadoop,dc=local" ldap_add: Type or value
>   exists (20)
>           additional info: cn: value #0 provided more than once

```
$vi ldap.ldif
dn: uid=impala,ou=Users,dc=hadoop,dc=local
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
uid: impala
sn: impala
givenName: impala
cn: impala
displayName: impala

dn: cn=impala,ou=Groups,dc=hadoop,dc=local
objectClass: top
objectClass: groupOfNames
cn: impala
member: uid=impala,ou=Users,dc=hadoop,dc=local
```

However I can add the records above individually 1 by 1 with no problem.

Comment: I really suspect newline is missing. What about checking `ldap.ldif` with `cat -A ldap.ldif`? (or a similar tool to highlight unprintable chars)

Comment: Thanks for the command. There was one unnecessary space besides just new line in between.

Answer (score 1):

### Note

User `473183469` answered the question via their comment, I'm going to just post an official answer with more context to make it more noticeable.

### Answer

When using LDIF files, [you can add multiple entries in a single file. Each entry must be separated by at least one completely blank line](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-ldif-files-to-make-changes-to-an-openldap-system#:%7E:text=You%20can%20add%20multiple%20entries%20in%20a%20single%20file.%20Each%20entry%20must%20be%20separated%20by%20at%20least%20one%20completely%20blank%20line%3A).  Herein lies your issue, **there is a single space next to the newline separating your two entries**.

If you use `cat -A` or, if that's not available, `cat -e` (`cat -A` wasn't available on my Mac) you can see a `$` at the end of each newline.  In your file, the output would look like the following.

```
❯ cat -e ldap.ldif
dn: uid=impala,ou=Users,dc=hadoop,dc=local$
objectClass: inetOrgPerson$
uid: impala$
sn: impala$
givenName: impala$
cn: impala$
displayName: impala$
 $
dn: cn=impala,ou=Groups,dc=hadoop,dc=local$
objectClass: top$
objectClass: groupOfNames$
cn: impala$
member: uid=impala,ou=Users,dc=hadoop,dc=local$
```

That single space besides the newline character is what is causing the issue. Note that [multiple lines can be used to provide long values for attribute by beginning the extra lines with a single space. LDAP will join these when processing the entry](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-ldif-files-to-make-changes-to-an-openldap-system#:%7E:text=Multiple%20lines%20can%20be%20used%20to%20provide%20long%20values%20for%20attribute%20by%20beginning%20the%20extra%20lines%20with%20a%20single%20space.%20LDAP%20will%20join%20these%20when%20processing%20the%20entry.).  This functionality is likely what is causing the issue as `ldapadd` is interpreting both entries as one large entry.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a - between entries?

```
dn: uid=impala,ou=Users,dc=hadoop,dc=local
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
uid: impala
sn: impala
givenName: impala
cn: impala
displayName: impala
-
dn: cn=impala,ou=Groups,dc=hadoop,dc=local
objectClass: top
objectClass: groupOfNames
cn: impala
member: uid=impala,ou=Users,dc=hadoop,dc=local
```

Comment: Doesn't work. The line with "-" returns an exception.

Comment: It returns an exception because on the line following the `-` does not contain data pertaining to `dn: uid=impala,ou=Users,dc=hadoop,dc=local` but data to a new onject. You need a blank line between the two.